# make related key array from multidimentioal array

Tags: php, arrays

how to read POST data from following form, for some reasons i am not using indexes like Customer[0][fullname] rather i am using Customer[][fullname]

```
<form action="form.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="Customer[][fullname]" />
<input type="text" name="Customer[][nic]" />
<input type="text" name="Customer[][fullname]" />
<input type="text" name="Customer[][nic]" />
<input type="text" name="Customer[][fullname]" />
<input type="text" name="Customer[][nic]" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Here is var_dump of my array

```
Array (
    [Customer] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [fullname] => abc
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [fullname] => def
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [fullname] => xyz
        )
        [3] => Array (
            [nic] => 111
        )
        [4] => Array (
            [nic] => 222
        )
        [5] => Array (
            [nic] => 333
        )
    )
)
```

I want to break above array like below array

```php
array("fullname"=>abc,"nic"=>111)
array("fullname"=>def,"nic"=>222)
array("fullname"=>xyz,"nic"=>333)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Where is this array coming from?  Why is is formatted in this way?

Comment: Iterating the array can easily solve the problem and I believe anyone who uses `var_dump` knows it very well, @RocketHazmat . I believe this question stands if there is some smart way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have come up with, it works for more than two fields as requested in a comment.

**Code:**

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array('fullname' => 'abc'),
    array('fullname' => 'def'),
    array('fullname' => 'ghi'),
    array('nic' => '111'),
    array('nic' => '222'),
    array('nic' => '333')
);
$index = 0;
foreach($array as $value) {
 if (!isset($old)) {
    $old = key($value);
 }
 if (key($value) != $old) {
    $index = 0;
    $old = key($value);
 }

 $result[$index][key($value)] = $value[key($value)];

 $index++;
}

print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => abc
            [nic] => 111
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => def
            [nic] => 222
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fullname] => ghi
            [nic] => 333
        )

)
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/BQAxdw)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$half = count($array['Customer'])/2;
for($i = 0; $i < $half; $i++) {
    $result[$i] = $array['Customer'][$i];
}
for($i = $half; $i < $half * 2; $i++) {
    $result[$i - $half] = array_merge($result[$i - $half], $array['Customer'][$i]);
}
```

Each value of `$result` will be what you wanted.

```
[0] => array('fullname'=>'abc','nic'=>111)
[1] => array('fullname'=>'def','nic'=>222)
[2] => array('fullname'=>'xyz','nic'=>333)
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, but most of the times variables are not known, i want to solve the issue without knowing variables names ie fullname,nic,phone, etc, so finally duplicate variable names should be stored in different arrays, there can be number of variables and a variable may exist more than 3 times,  we can not fix any thing in logic

Comment: your code is working great if there are only two fields, i wonder if i get the code for any of array elements.

Comment: @G.Muqtada Check my new answer. I think I have your solution!